# Membership API WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, asp.net-membership

I have a question that I have researched a lot but cannot find any solid proven answers for yet.

I have a Web Application that I am developing, potentially using Membership API for user membership and authentication. This works great when people login from their browsers. This has been tried and tested and it just works great.

I want to extend the same 'Registration/Login' functionality from my WP7 (Windows Phone). Now my questions are:
1. What is the best approach to do the same?
2. Can I use WCF to do the same? I know I could use the Cookie Container approach, but this will cause issues on removal of cookies etc right?

I want the WP7 app work such that once the user logs in, he remains logged in.

1. Will I have to write my own OAuth2 provider? If yes, can someone please provide me with any good links that give me examples.

Even better, have people developed their own WP7 applications that use User Registration and Authentication? Any insights would help.

I understand that Azure now has Access Control that allows me to link in with Hotmail, Facebook etc to validate a user. In this scenario, how can I ensure that I still link this authentication with an Internal User identifier?

I am a little confused with the plethora of options and not a single popular blog explains this clearly (NOT that I have come across, yet!)

I would highly appreciate insights.

Regards,
Anup

Comment: Explain what your current "membership API" has and how you use it on the website. We can than advise on how to integrate within your app.

Comment: Hello, I am using the std. ASP.NET Membership API that can allow a user to register with email/password, change password, login etc.

Answer (score 0):

there is a walkthrough for connecting with ACS & windows Phone 7 (including source files) on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg192968

hope this helps